# Change <title> in a wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have this wordpress page where I use this theme called 'Total', I want to change the `<title>`, but it is not inside the header file (edit theme), and if I write it, it will automatically be changed for a default title that is provided god knows where.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEysh.jpg)

Comment: Chances are the title is in the actual content template for pages rather than the header.  The header will normally have the title for the site but not for the actual page you're viewing.  Look inside the page.php template or if there's a directory called 'template-parts', there'll be a template part in there for page content.

Comment: If you don't mind creating a child theme, you could hook into [`wp_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/) to change your title.

Comment: I have used wp_title and several other option in the functions.php and nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

This theme uses a visual editor, WPBakery, so it's not as straight forward as native WP. Can you add a screen shot. And a little clearer question. Having trouble figuring out exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I placed the image in the question

Comment: That just shows a part of the screen., and is not helpful Can you go to the page in question, in edit and screenshot the whole page?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Title and Tagline

1. Log in to the WordPress Dashboard.
2. On the left in the sidebar, hover over “Settings” and click General.
3. List item The “Site title” and the “Tagline” can be changed here. Enter a new title and tagline. Click Save Changes. Now Visit your WordPress the site and you will see the title and tagline changed.